# Disable Taskbar in Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows-10

Is there any way to **completely** disable the taskbar in Windows 10 Home? I have a C# app that I want to display fullscreen on clients' displays without any sign of it running on Windows. It's supposed to run on startup and display a website.

I created a setup that changes most of the Windows settings via registry, like hiding desktop icons and altering logon view, but the taskbar remains visible. Auto hide doesn't satisfy me, because after the system boots the taskbar is still visible until you actually click somewhere on the desktop, and it takes a while for my app to run. I'd really appreciate some help.

Comment: *Kiosk mode* is the way to do this, check if its supported on the Home edition.

Comment: If you use wpf you could use windowmode="none" and fullscreen, which would hide the taskbar. However alt + tab is still possible

Comment: I don't think kiosk mode is supported on the Home edition, and kiosk mode requires a UWP app. You are probably not writing one of those. Don't make it too difficult, though: just [change the shell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms838576.aspx) to your application.

Comment: @AlexK. Kiosk is only on Win Professional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When explorer is running, there taskbar will always be visible in some kind (even if it's a small border).

If you want to achieve something like a digital signage solution, you may replace the shell. Changing the shell will also provide some other benefits (most popups / balloontips won't occur anymore).
Be aware that this configuration is effective for all users on the system.

Path to the shell is available at

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WinLogon\Shell
```

---

**Update:**

Just to hightlight: 
It is indeed possible to have custom shells per user (see comments).
This is done by specifying a custom location of the shell path that is located in the registry for a given user.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. It also eliminates the need for editing user's theme settings. Thanks!
However, I had to edit one more key for this to work:  

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\IniFileMapping\system.ini\boot\Shell`  
Please refer to @CodyGray 's comment under question for link to MSDN article about this.

Answer (score 0):

make the window occupy the entire desktop;

```
// go full screen
ResizeMode  = ResizeMode.NoResize;
WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;

// return to normal window
ResizeMode  = ResizeMode.CanResize;
WindowStyle = WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow;
WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
```